# How to detect root screen and get child view of the screen in react-native

Tags: react-native

HI i was working with android and new to react-native.I am stuck to find out view from screen like i get in Android using findViewByID. in android i can use activity's object for getting any view form there id's but in react-native there is no option like that.
SO anyone who is expert can help me in this.

i have set ref of the main view and set id and key for text view and button.
I want to fetch button's view using the id or the key. Please let me know the possible ways to do that.